# 'components' folder not showing in lit-element

Tags: html, polymer, lit-element

My project isn't working when I name a folder 'components', if I named any other name('component', 'pasta', 'templates') it works. The route names are fine, this **ONLY** happens when the folder it's named 'components'.

I'm using [lit-element](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/) in this project

## It works

[image: It works]

## Doesn't work

[image: Doesn't work]

## Steps to reproduce

```
npm i lit-element
touch index.html // Create a HTML file in the root folder
mkdir components // Create a folder where JS components will be
touch main.js // Create a component file
cd ..; polymer serve // Go back one directory and run the project
```

```js
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class MyElement extends LitElement {
    render() {
        return html`<p>template content</p>`;
    }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script type="module" src="./components/main.js"></script>
    <title>lit-element code sample</title>
</head>

<body>
    <my-element></my-element>
</body>

</html>
```

> **NOTE** this snippet code doesn't run in StackOverflow, create the project and reproduce it.

Change the name of the 'components' folder to any name you want, then change the route in the `index.html` file.

Comment: Could you please show the code defining the component and how you're importing it in the html?

Comment: I edit the question, if you have any more questions please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the log, `polymer serve` reserves a namespace starting with `components/` for serving reusable components (a legacy of [Polymer's old `bower_components` dependency management](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#element-project-layout)). This prevents your `components` folder from being served correctly. The namespace should be configurable through the `--component-url` option, although it [doesn't seem to work](https://github.com/Polymer/tools/issues/3495).

You can either

- use `polyserve` directly and change the component url:

  ```
  $ npm i -g polyserve
  $ polyserve --component-url mycustomcomponenturl
  ```
- use another dev server: open-wc's [`es-dev-server`](https://open-wc.org/developing/es-dev-server.html) is a great alternative, also cited by the lit-html docs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to web, is there any reserved directories names I should know about?

Comment: Glad I could help :) Well, I would say the omnipresent one is `node_modules`, but apart from that you should generally be able to structure your project folder as you want.